# I can't get env var in the Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, containers, lxc, lxc-docker

I've ran my Docker container using this command:
`docker run --name test1 -d -e FLAG='***' rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd`
Now, when I connect to it via SSH, I can't get my env there via `printenv FLAG`.
How can I fix this? When running with `-it` and `sh`, I can my get env via `printenv FLAG`.

Comment: Maybe envs passed using `-e` are used only for entrypoint and aren't set in container environment?

Comment: Do you see it if you do `docker exec test1 env` ?

Comment: @Alkaline yes! but if I connect via ssh and run `env` I don't see it

Comment: u need to read this article: https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/, especially part about variables

Answer (score 4):

> Now, when I connect to it via SSH, I can't get my env there via
>   printenv FLAG. How can I fix this? When running with -it and sh, I can
>   my get env via printenv FLAG

You are doing two different things:

- `docker run -it -e FLAG='***' rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd sh` will run a container in interactive mode with a shell, and **this shell session will have the environment variable** you passed on the command line. With `docker run -d -e FLAG='***' rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd`, a SSH daemon process will start with defined env vars.
- when you connect in the container with SSH you will create a **new shell session which does not have these environment variable set**.

This can be observed when running a container, connecting to it using ssh and showing all processes and their environment variable:

```
docker run -d -p 2222:22 -e FLAG='test' rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd
ssh root@localhost -p 2222
...
```

We are now connected into the container, we can see the SSH daemon process (PID 1) and our SSH session process (PID 7):

```
root@788fa982c2d0:~# ps -xf
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D  # <== does have the FLAG env var
    7 ?        Ss     0:00 sshd: root@pts/0   # <== no FLAG env var
```

Lets check it out, print our current process env var, and the env var of the SSH daemon process:

```
root@788fa982c2d0:~# printenv FLAG # Nothing
root@788fa982c2d0:~# cat /proc/1/environ # We see the FLAG env var!
[..]FLAG=test[...]
```

As pointed out by @Dmitrii, you can read [Dockerize an SSH service](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Try Using below Command:

```
docker exec <container-id> bash -c 'echo "$<variable-name>"'
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/) 
you might need to create your own Dockerfile with following changes

```
Project  
|--Dockerfile  
|--entrypoint.sh
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

File: entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "export FLAG=$FLAG" >> /etc/profile
exec "$@"
```

Command:

```
 docker build -t your-ubuntu-sshd .
 docker run --name test1 -d -e FLAG='abc' -p 2222:22 your-ubuntu-sshd
```